# Random's randint won't work in a for-loop

Tags: for-loop, random, python-3.4

I'm trying to create a list with random length filled with lists of random lengths by using this code:

```
import random

solitaire = [None]*(random.randint(1,5)) 

for pile in solitaire:
    number = random.randint(0, 10)
    solitaire.append(number)    

print(solitaire)
```

Easy enough I thought but when I ran this code my powershell window froze as it was expecting an input or something, I had to cancel the script with ctr+c and then got the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sparakod.py", line 254, in <module>
number = random.randint(0, 10)
File "C:\Python34\lib\random.py", line 218, in randint
return self.randrange(a, b+1)
File "C:\Python34\lib\random.py", line 170, in randrange
def randrange(self, start, stop=None, step=1, _int=int):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

What does this mean? Why won't the code run?

```
 number = random.randint(0, 10)
```

Seems to work just fine so why won't it inside the for-loop?

Comment: It may be illuminating to add a `print solitaire` statement inside your loop.

Comment: You keep adding items to the very list you're iterating over. One of the possible resulting behaviors is for the loop to never end.

Comment: Oh, quite illuminating indeed! Thank you very much both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't say anything about the content of the lists, supposing that they also contain random integers, then a possible solution could be the following:

```py
"""
It creates a list with random length filled with lists of random lengths containing random integers

"""


import random

MIN_LIST_OF_LISTS_LENGTH = 1
MAX_LIST_OF_LISTS_LENGTH = 10

MIN_LIST_LENGTH = 1
MAX_LIST_LENGTH = 5

MIN_LIST_ELEMENT = 1
MAX_LIST_ELEMENT = 10


#This is the list which will containt all the lists
solitaire = list(range(random.randint(MIN_LIST_OF_LISTS_LENGTH,MAX_LIST_OF_LISTS_LENGTH)))


for i, pile in enumerate(solitaire):
    solitaire[i] = [
        random.randint(MIN_LIST_ELEMENT, MAX_LIST_ELEMENT) for x in
        range(0, random.randint(MIN_LIST_LENGTH, MAX_LIST_LENGTH))
    ]

print(repr(solitaire))
```

It will generate outputs like these:

```
[[10, 3], [5, 2, 7, 7, 6], [5], [9, 3, 2, 6], [2, 4, 4], [4, 5, 10, 9, 10]]
```

or

```
[[5, 1], [5, 1, 1], [1, 1, 7, 3, 1]]
```

or

```
[[9, 1, 6, 7], [10, 7, 1, 7, 4]]
```